# Detecting hand written X and find its center (intersection of the two lines forming an X)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working with opencv and need some technique to achieve the following,

1. what could be the best way to detect handwritten Xs in an image? also how to find the center of each X? given that the background could be white or vary.
   sample images are attached

[image: Handwritten X1]
[image: Handwritten X2]
[image: Handwritten X3]
_

2. is there is a way to detect handwritten English characters (alphabets) in general? (this is out of the scope of the original question?)

Comment: This is too broad to warrant a single answer.

Comment: what's too broad exactly, let's say I just want to detect hand written Xs in a given image, what should be my approach using opencv ? I'm sorry but I'm new to image processing

Comment: This is an interesting question. Do some experimentation on your own. Edit your question, post your code and results. For starters read this link: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: @Zindarod I've played around with contours but I'm not sure about that approach (tried approxPolyDP but didn't get a consistent count for all Xs), should I use ML for this or is it an overkill?

Comment: @AbdooFathy Why should ML be an overkill? If you haven't found a solution anywhere else and you know enough ML to make it work then use it.

Comment: I will try and update the question if reached anything useful, thank you

Comment: see [handwritten-digits-classification-an-opencv-c-python-tutorial](http://www.learnopencv.com/handwritten-digits-classification-an-opencv-c-python-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

What i am going to suggest is possible theoretically.

When you are going to write "X" draw 4 circles to it's corners. And use finding circle algorithm of opencv. Search it so basic to use. The function will give the center of circles as output to you. Then draw line between cross circles. If those 2 lines intersects it is an X and the intersection point is the center you are looking for. Basic geometry. You can do all with 30 mins google search if you are familiar with coding.

Comment: I've implemented that & it works but I'm afraid this will misdetect a plus sign also. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Manipulate angles better. Say if angle between lines > 75 its plus sign.